# How to "permanently" protect text in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to make some selected text protected in `RichTextBox`. I tried something like this:

```
MouseClickEvent(...)
{
   if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
   {
      SelectionProtected = true;
   }
}
```

When I do this, it protects selected text until the selection is cleared. How can I make this protection permanent?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionprotected.aspx) says:

> If this property is set to true, the [`Protected` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.protected.aspx) is raised when the user attempts to change the current text selection.

So, it seems to me, that you would simply reject the user's attempt to modify the protected text in the control inside of a handler method attached to the `Protected` event.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I reject that event? (I am new to c#)